# Uninstalling PowerShell 1.0 before installing SharePoint 2010

Tags: powershell, installation

While going through the book "Beginning SharePoint 2010 Administration", the author was discussing how to prepare for a SharePoint 2010 server installation on a Windows 2008 R2 server. In that one of the steps being uninstalling PowerShell 1.0. I don't understand the reason behind this.

Why should one uninstall PowerShell 1.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly PowerShell 1.0 (or some later version like 1.0 CTP something) is default PowerShell version on Windows 2008 Server (not R2). SharePoint 2010 uses PowerShell 2.0. If PowerShell 1.0 is already installed on your server you will have to uninstall it. Before running actual SharePoint installation run **Install software prerequisites** and this wizard will check if all the necessary prerequisites are installed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now i understand the reason why the author told to do so.

Comment: I didn't need to uninstall 1.0 before installing 2.0 when making a development server. Do you really 'have to uninstall it'? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Because it was a must with the CTP versions of PowerShell V2.

With the community previous this was not possible, and further you could not uninstall PowerShell V1 when there were Service Packs installed and even some PowerShell MVP told me, that the only way would be to uninstall the service pack, than uninstall PowerShell V1, reinstall the Servicepack and install PowerShell V2. I'm very glad that he was wrong. The final version did better.

I succeeded to update to PowerShell V2 without uninstall on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP.

I did not yet try it with Windows 2008.